# Invalid type signature: TabelaProdutos :: ...?

Tags: haskell

Can you help me to fiz this error? Thank you.
Do not know why my Produto Type is not being recognized as a type for my function header ... Could you help me?

```
--" Invalid type signature: TabelaProdutos :: ...
-- Should be of form <variable> :: <type> "

type Codigo     = Int
type Nome       = [Char]
type Preco      = Int
type Produtos   = [(Codigo, Nome, Preco)] -- Type Product defined here
type Carrinho   = [Codigo]
type Conta      = [(Nome, Preco)]

TabelaProdutos :: Produtos          -- THE ERROR OCCURS IN THAT LINE
TabelaProdutos =  [(001, "Chocolate", 121)
                  ,(002, "Biscoito", 1010)
                  ,(003, "Laranja", 56)
                  ,(004, "Sabao", 21)
                  ,(005, "Batata Chips", 133)
                  ,(006, "Doritos", 450)
                  ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions in Haskell must begin with a lowercase letter. Change the function name to `tabelaProdutos` and you should be fine.